# Facebook logout button not showing after customize default code

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, backbone.js

I want to customize the default Facebook login button using css in my backbone project.

This is what I did  :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '285660138255145',
        status     : true,
        xfbml      : true
    });
  };
  function fb_login(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
            user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                user_email = response.email; //get user email
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {
        scope: 'publish_stream,email'
    });
}

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)){ return; }
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=285660138255145";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<div style="position: relative; left: 16px; top: 10px;">
  <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" onclick="fb_login();">
      <span class="icon icon-fb"></span>
      <span class="title">Login with Facebook</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

After adding two spans in `<div class="fb-login-button">`, Even an account is successfully log in, the sign in button still show, that should be Log out button here.

It will work if :

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 16px; top: 10px;">
  <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" onclick="fb_login();">
     //text.... not <span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>
```

Notice

```
data-auto-logout-link="true"
```

**Another thing -**
You don't have `App Id` in your code. Add it. You will get an `app id` by creating an app on facebook. You can't use the `fb login plugin` without the `app Id`.

```
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID_SHOULD_BE_HERE";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Notice the **YOUR_APP_ID_SHOULD_BE_HERE** part.

**Update:**

On basis of your comments, the below code works for me and should work for everyone if you are successful in logging a person into your app. The code is for a customized button. And yes, if you redirect to another page right after login then definitely you might not be able to see the logout button in that fraction of second before redirection.

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" scope="email" data-auto-logout-link="true" width="200" max-rows="1">Connect with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Comment: I've update my question, please have a look at `<div class="fb-login-button".....`

Comment: Added `app id`, Nothing have changed.

Comment: I've updated my question, and added code at the bottom of the question!

Comment: It works! But is it possible to hide `Be the first of your friends to use.....` text?

Comment: I think that's default functionality of fb. I haven't tried it yet. Btw, if it works for you, you should upvote and accept for others to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
$ses_user=$this->session->userdata('User');
if(empty($ses_user))   
{ 
    echo img(array('src'=>$base_url.'images/facebook.png','id'=>'facebook','style'=>'cursor:pointer;float:left;margin-left:550px;'));

 }  
else
{
    echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'. $ses_user['id'] .'/picture" width="30" height="30"/><div>'.$ses_user['name'].'</div>';    
    echo '<a href="'.$this->session->userdata('logout').'">Logout</a>';     
}
?>
```

Comment: Currently I'm using backbone.js to develop my project, so could you answer it in javascript?